# Getting "Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, internal-server-error

At my job, we have a service that processes JSON files.

Usually, it will split a larger file into smaller files so it can multithread and process more splits faster.
Occassionally, we'll see an API Communication Failure message, and when looking into the logs, I'll see this: "Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)"

It doesn't happen all of the time, but a few times an hour. We have very high traffic, so its not even a large percentage of the files that are failing. Could someone please shed some light on what could possibly be wrong?

Here is the code where it is happening:

```
public class CommunicationAPI
{
    static int iAPIConnectionTimeOut = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIConnectionTimeOut"]); //15 minutes, so a timeout isn't the issue.

    public static async Task<string> PostInboundActivityAsync(string sUrl, string sContent, long lSysServiceThread)
    {
        string sResponse = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(iAPIConnectionTimeOut);
                StringContent strContent = new StringContent("'" + sContent + "'", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = client.PostAsync(sUrl, strContent);

                var apiResponse = await response;
                if (apiResponse != null && HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed == apiResponse.StatusCode)
                {
                    return sResponse = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    apiResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
                sResponse = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                // check if we received response 'OK' 200 status
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sResponse))
                {
                    sResponse = apiResponse.ReasonPhrase;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.WriteToThreadLog("Exception in API Call :" + ex.Message, lSysServiceThread);

            sResponse = "EXCEPTION";
        }

        return sResponse;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked for errors in your logs? BTW I strongly recommend you to log the full stacktrace of the exception, not only the message.

Comment: If you get statuscode 500 you should see an error in your log

Comment: This goes through at least two API calls. One log i see nothing in, and the other log i just see that it's got the 500 message. Its nothing that really helps me. And I'm tasked with figuring out what's going wrong currently without changing any code. But yes, I know we should have better logging. (I didn't write any of this code, haha)

Comment: The Http status code error of 500 is an "Internal Server Error". That error is coming from the service. Is this a service that you own and can do logging in?

Comment: "Not changing any code" might exclude temporarily adding tracing/debugging statements. Otherwise you might never find the cause.

Comment: This looks like the client code, but the error is happening on the server. You’d need to post the server code if you want help diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Might not be relevant for the issue, but you are making blocking calls to awaitables (`.Result`) in an async task. Why? On the other hand, response will never be null and you will probably never get result code 412 with this request. Try to log the exact request and response when you get 500. If you cant, neither can you debug for whatever reason, use a network sniffer.